# how to make laptop sleep while external monitor connected (fan still spins)

Tags: multiple-monitors

I have a HP Pavilion DV6 6053ea laptop, i recently got a Dell external monitor, after a while of not using the laptop the external monitor goes black but the laptop fan still spins.

I have enabled (Win key + 'P') external monitor

Is there anything I can do to make the laptop go to sleep like it would normally with no external monitor ?

Comment: there's a command to see what's stopping a comp from sleeping  http://lifehacker.com/5924010/how-to-find-out-whats-keeping-your-computer-from-going-to-sleep     `powercfg -requests`

Comment: thanks ! I'm setting it to sleep in start... nothing comes up that says something is stopping it from sleeping.

Comment: what if you try to put the comp to sleep from start menu, (not waiting), and you try it with the monitor connected. Does it work, or fail?